# Jacobi matrix for: $h: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m, x \mapsto Ax-b$

Tags: matrices, analysis, numerical-methods, jacobian

How can I determine the Jacobi matrix for:

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb R^m$

$h: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m, x \mapsto Ax-b$

For a mapping like the following it is clear to me:

$f(x,y,z) = \binom{x^2+y^2+z \cdot sin x}{z^2+z \cdot sin y}$

**Question**: How can I get the Jacobi matrix for a general mapping like $h$?

I have tried to understand it with the help of an example:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        11 & 12 & 13 & 14 
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        x_4 
        \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix}
        3x_1+4x_2+5x_3+6x_4 \\
        7x_1+8x_2+9x_3+10x_4\\
        11x_!+12x_2+13x_3+14x_4
        \end{pmatrix} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
        \sum_{j=1, i=1}^m A_{ij}x_i \\
        \vdots \\
        \sum_{j=1, i=n}^m A_{ij}x_i 
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, I have updated my question

Comment: So $A$ is a matrix, and you are seeking a matrix...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have tried to generlize it to a matrix (see my updated post) but I still do not have an idea...

Answer (score 2):

The expression you wrote at the end of your question is really close to the solution.
You have $$Ax+b=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_j A_{1j}x_j+b_1\\
\vdots\\
\sum_j A_{nj}x_j+b_n
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The Jacobian matrix $J$ is the matrix whose coordinates are $J_{ij}=\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}$.
Here $h_i=\sum_j A_{ij}x_j+b_i$ and $\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}=A_{ij}$.
Thus $J_{ij}=A_{ij}$ and $J=A$.